# Calendar for online meetings

Tags: events, web, web-applications, calendar

I need an online application in which I share to a bunch of people (by their emails) a time period, with a certain granularity. Let's say one week from day X to day Y, with time slots of 1 hour and half, and asking people to fill them in order to book their slot (they should see slot availability). Is there a free web app that is capable of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I regularly use google calendar to invite/share with my colleagues for the meetings. It allows them to respond yes/no to my invitation. I also use it for scheduling my busy work slots so that it will remind me of at the right time. If you need to know more about setting up sharing appointment slots in Google calendar, you can refer at

https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/190998?hl=en

There are also other meeting scheduler apps that might suits well for your needs; please see the following.

**Reference 1:** https://zapier.com/blog/best-meeting-scheduler-apps/#timebridge

**Reference 2:** http://mashable.com/2012/09/20/shared-calendar-apps/#FOLZrYKZ.8qE

Comment: but if I want to let them book in a time period a slot , is it possible for them to see the availability of these time slots? (if already taken or not).